# $\nabla^2u > 0 $, show that $u$ cannot have a maximum in the interior of the unit disk.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $u$ be a $C^2$ function on the unit disk which is "strictly subharmonic", that is $$\nabla^2u = \frac {\partial^2 u} {\partial x^2} + \frac {\partial^2 u} {\partial y^2} > 0 $$
Show that $u$ cannot have a maximum point in $D\setminus \partial D$ where $\partial D$ is the boundary of $D$.

I have just finished a chapter where I learned about the first and second derivative test in a multi-variate setting, but I am not at all sure how to parse this question. I know that $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} > 0 $ does not imply that
$\frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial x^2} > 0 $ , so how can I show that if $(x_0,y_0)$ is a max or min point, then it must be on the unit disk?

Comment: No need to define the Laplacean.

Comment: Note that $\nabla^2 u$ is the trace (sum of diagonal entries) of the Hessean matrix, which must be negative semidefinite at a local maximum.

Comment: On the other hand,  minima in the interior of the disk are of course possible for subharmonic function, e.g. for $u(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: @HansEngler can you elaborate on why your first comment is true?

Comment: Actually the condition can be relaxed to $\nabla^2 u \ge 0$ and the conclusion will still hold.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum of strictly subharmonic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246668/maximum-of-strictly-subharmonic-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose it did: Then there would be a point in the interior of the disc with 
$$
u(x_0,y_0)
$$
at a maximum. This then implies that $\Delta u(x_0,y_0)\leq 0$, since the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues, and the laplacian is the trace of the hessian matrix which must be negative semidefinite at a maximum. But this isn't quite what we need: What if instead we look at the following function
$$
v(x,y)=u(x,y)+\epsilon (x^2+y^2)
$$
with epsilon small enough such that $(x_0,y_0)$ is still a maximum for $v$? Such an $\epsilon$ surely exists thanks to your domain being bounded. Then we have
$$
\Delta v(x,y)=\Delta u(x,y)+4\epsilon=4\epsilon \implies \Delta v(x_0,y_0)=4\epsilon>0
$$
a contradiction, since the hessian for $v$ must be negative semidefinite at $(x_0,y_0)$ for $v$ to attain an interior minimum.

edit: The above proof is for harmonic functions. If instead one has that $\Delta u(x,y)>0$ for all $x,y\in D$, then an immediate contradiction is derived from assuming an interior maximum: By the same logic as the above, at such a point $(x_0,y_0)\in D\setminus \partial D$ 
$$
\Delta u(x_0,y_0)\leq 0
$$ 
a contradiction.

Comment: Your $\epsilon$ argument doesn't quite work. Consider e.g. $u(x,y) = -x^4 - y^4$ which has a local maximum at the origin. But every $v$ of the form given in your answer has a local minimum at the origin.

Comment: @HansEngler oh my lord I completely misread in my haste and thought they said harmonic. fixing

Comment: @HansEngler should be fine now